# How do I specify a named animation for .animate()?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am making a game with plain HTML, not any canvas.  In it, I have made an animation that moves the circles and squares to the bottom of the page, called `ttb`, for `to the bottom`.

When a circle finishes its animation, I would like it to stop the animations of all other circles/squares.  After some research, I came over [Element.animate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/pause).  It looked perfect, but when I saw the code:

```js
// animation of the cupcake slowly getting eaten up
var nommingCake = document.getElementById('eat-me_sprite').animate(
[
  { transform: 'translateY(0)' },
  { transform: 'translateY(-80%)' }
], {
  fill: 'forwards',
  easing: 'steps(4, end)',
  duration: aliceChange.effect.timing.duration / 2
});

// doesn't actually need to be eaten until a click event, so pause it initially:
nommingCake.pause();
```

It looks like it can only pause an animation that was started with `.animate()`.  When I found [.animate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate), I looked at its code and this was the example:

```js
document.getElementById("tunnel").animate([
  // keyframes
  { transform: 'translateY(0px)' },
  { transform: 'translateY(-300px)' }
], {
  // timing options
  duration: 1000,
  iterations: Infinity
});
```

It creates an animation with an array, but as I've already created the animation with CSS, do I have to make it again with JS or can I simply give the name of the animation (`ttb`) as some type of argument to animate it that way?  I need to use `.animate()` because only then I can pause the animation.

**Edit:**

Here's my code:

```js
function chance(c){return (Math.floor(Math.random()*c)+1)==c;}
setInterval(function(){
    if(chance(7)){
        var o=document.createElement("div");
        var s=chance(2);
        var t=chance(2);
        o.className=(t?"left ":"right ")+(s?"circle":"square")+" ttb";
        if(s){
            o.onanimationend=function(){end("You lost");};
        }else o.onanimationend=function(){try{this.parentNode.removeChild(this);}catch(e){}};
        document.body.appendChild(o);
    };
},500);
function end(m){
    var i=[].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("square")).concat([].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("circle")));
    var l;
    console.log(m);
    for(l=i.length-1;l>-1;l--)i[l].parentNode.removeChild(i[l]);
    // the above removes all of the elements
    // I would like that it stops their animations instead
}
```

```css
@keyframes ttb{from{top:-50px;}to{top:100vh}}
.square{position:absolute;width:50px;height:50px;border-radius:10px}
.circle{position:absolute;width:50px;height:50px;border-radius:50%}
.left{background-color:#FF2211}
.right{background-color:#4488FF}
.ttb{animation:ttb 3s linear 0s 1 forwards}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:#113355;overflow:hidden">
</body>
```

Comment: Have you investigated putting an eventlistener on each circle - to listen for the 'ended' event. Then when that fires, stop the animations of  other elements. Please put your code in a snippet so we can see what's needed.

Comment: @AHaworth: OK, I added my code.  I hope I named everything that matters in a way you can understand.  `chance` returns `1` in a chance of `1/(parameter passed)`.  `end()` is the function that ends the game.

Comment: Any HTML/CSS? It would help if you could make a proper SO snippet so we can see what's happeing.

Comment: @AHaworth: Hopefully, it's easier to see what's happening now.  Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the animations created from CSS through [`document.getAnimations()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/getAnimations), then you can filter the returned array by the `animationName` of the returned [Animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation) objects and cancel, finish or pause it as you wish:

```js
function chance(c){return (Math.floor(Math.random()*c)+1)==c;}
setInterval(function(){
    if(chance(2)){
        var o=document.createElement("div");
        var s=chance(2);
        var t=chance(2);
        o.className=(t?"left ":"right ")+(s?"circle":"square")+" ttb";
        if(s){
            o.onanimationend=function(){end("You lost");};
        }else o.onanimationend=function(){try{this.parentNode.removeChild(this);}catch(e){}};
        document.body.appendChild(o);
    };
},500);
function end(m){
  const animations = document.getAnimations().filter( (anim) => anim.animationName === "ttb" );
  // not sure what you want, here I just pause active ones
  animations.forEach( anim => anim.pause() );
  console.log( m );
}
```

```css
@keyframes ttb{from{top:-50px;}to{top:100vh}}
.square{position:absolute;width:50px;height:50px;border-radius:10px}
.circle{position:absolute;width:50px;height:50px;border-radius:50%}
.left{background-color:#FF2211}
.right{background-color:#4488FF}
.ttb{animation:ttb 3s linear 0s 1 forwards}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:#113355;overflow:hidden">
</body>
```